# Get value of BigDecimal created from string

Tags: java

I have created a BigDecimal with a scale of 2 like

```java
BigDecimal decimal = new BigDecimal("5.99");
```

How can I extract the value of the bigdecimal to get 599?

Comment: Please explain the logic of how `5.99` becomes `599`.

Comment: What do you mean? the value of the big decimal is not 599, it is 5.99

Comment: So do you want multiply the value in the string by 100 for the final value?

Comment: Call toString() then replace the periods with blanks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is straightforward: it's just [`bigDecimal.unscaledValue()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html#unscaledValue()) to get the significant digits of the BigDecimal without a decimal point or a raise to a power of ten.